# two-member relationship R maths

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and we have the  two-member relationship :

> $R=\{(a,a),(a,c),(c,c),(c,b),(b,b),(a,d),(d,d),(b,d)\}$

is it $R$ partial order?

is any way  that I  can solve it and give me the right answer?

Comment: Whar does "$R$ ordinance" mean?

Comment: I don't know how to discribe it I did with google translate ,other similar words are set-up,layout

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, sorry.  My only guess would be along the lines of "Is $R$ an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)?" which it clearly isn't.  Perhaps try asking it in the original language?

Comment: How do you say it in your language?

Comment: when it is like this  https://ibb.co/KhSP1s1 its called R ordinance

Comment: @lulu yes that's right

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso partial order is the word  I have edited

Comment: Well, $R$ is clearly not an equivalence relation since it is not symmetric ($(a,c)$ is in $R$ but $(c,a)$ is not) nor is it transitive ($(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ are in $R$ but $(a,b)$ is not).

Comment: yes I see it too. Does exists any softwrare or program or something else to check it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial order has to satisfy (1) $aRa$ for all $a$; (2) if $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aRc$; (3) for $a\ne b$, at most one of $aRb$ and $bRa$ holds.

Your R has $aRc$ and $cRb$ but not $aRb$, so it is not a partial order (in the jargon, it is not transitive).

Comment: is any software ,or calculator that I can do alone that?

Comment: Not that I know of. But why do you need it? You just check (1): do we have all of $aRa,bRb,cRc,dRd$? Answer: yes. So the relation is reflexive. Do we have both $xRy$ and $yRx$ for any pair $x\ne y$. Answer: no. So the relation is anti-symmetric. But then when we check whether it is transitive, we find that it isn't. So even worst case where you find the flaw on your last check, the whole process only takes a couple of minutes.